# Hide icons in a nav bar and show only text on hover

Tags: html, css

I am working on a navigation sidebar with icons which on hover display text along with icon with reference to JFarrow's https://codepen.io/JFarrow/pen/fFrpg

```
<li>
  <a href="http://justinfarrow.com">
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
    <span class="nav-text">Dashboard</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

But in my case I would like to hide icons when I hover on the sidebar and display only text.

**May I know a best way to do this?**

Comment: You should add an `EventListener` on the sidebar to trigger the icons to hide and only show text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure css solution would be the next:
Hope this helps

Hice icon image

```
nav.main-menu:hover i:before {
    display: none;
}
```

Adapt sidebar width

```
nav.main-menu:hover {
width:200px;
}
```

Reduce icon space

```
nav.main-menu:hover .fa{
width: 10px;
}
```

Added snipet so everyone can try it

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);

}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.main-menu:hover,
nav.main-menu.expanded {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-menu {
  background: #212121;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
  transition: width .05s linear;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.main-menu>ul {
  margin: 7px 0;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
}
.main-menu li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  color: #999;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
.main-menu .nav-icon {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.main-menu .nav-text {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
.main-menu>ul.logout {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,
nav.main-menu li.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,
.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,
.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5fa2db;
}
.area {
  float: left;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
nav.main-menu:hover i:before {
  display: none;
}
nav.main-menu:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
nav.main-menu:hover .fa {
  width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="area"></div>
  <nav class="main-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="http://justinfarrow.com">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Dashboard
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            UI Components
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Forms
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li class="has-subnav">
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Pages
                        </span>
        </a>

      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Graphs and Statistics
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Typography and Icons
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Tables
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Maps
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Documentation
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="logout">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i>
          <span class="nav-text">
                            Logout
                        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set `width:0` and `visibility:hidden` to the `fa` on `.main-menu:hover`

Also use `flexbox`...don't use table on `<a>` elements.

```
.main-menu:hover .fa {
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

***Stack Snippet***

```css
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css);

}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:300);
.fa-2x {
  font-size: 2em;
}
.fa {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.main-menu:hover,
nav.main-menu.expanded {
  width: 250px;
  overflow: visible;
}
.main-menu {
  background: #212121;
  border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
  transition: width .05s linear;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  z-index: 1000;
}
.main-menu>ul {
  margin: 7px 0;
}
.main-menu li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
}
.main-menu li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-spacing: 0;
  color: #999;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .1s linear;
}
.main-menu .nav-icon {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.main-menu .nav-text {
  position: relative;
  width: 190px;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
.main-menu>ul.logout {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.no-touch .scrollable.hover {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.no-touch .scrollable.hover:hover {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow: visible;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
nav ul,
nav li {
  outline: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main-menu li:hover>a,
nav.main-menu li.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus,
.no-touch .dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li:hover a,
.dashboard-page nav.dashboard-menu ul li.active a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #5fa2db;
}
.area {
  float: left;
  background: #e2e2e2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Titillium WebLight'), local('TitilliumWeb-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/titilliumweb/v2/anMUvcNT0H1YN4FII8wpr24bNCNEoFTpS2BTjF6FB5E.woff) format('woff');
}
.main-menu:hover .fa {
  width: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.main-menu:hover a {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="area"></div>
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://justinfarrow.com"><i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Dashboard</span></a></li>
    <li class="has-subnav"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-laptop fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">UI Components</span></a></li>
    <li class="has-subnav"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Forms</span></a></li>
    <li class="has-subnav"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Pages</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Graphs and Statistics</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-font fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Typography and Icons</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-table fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Tables</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Maps</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Documentation</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="logout">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x"></i><span class="nav-text">Logout</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Default the icon to display none and then add hover css property. Something like this,

```
           <li>
                  <a href="http://justinfarrow.com">
                    <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x my_icon"></i>
                    <span class="nav-text">
                        Dashboard
                    </span>
                </a>

            </li>

           <style>
             .my_icon{
                         display :none;
                  }

            .my_icon:hover{
                         display :visible;
                  }
           </style>
```